# Codeigniter: Customize ordering query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to achieve doing `ORDER BY task_status = 'Open'`
but I am unable to get the result.

I did this

```
$this->db->from('session_tasks');
$this->db->order_by('task_status', 'OPEN', 'DESC');        
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I hope anyone can help.

Comment: What are the options available in `task_status`?

Comment: @RohanKumar there are Close, Open, Paid, Pending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM session_tasks
         ORDER BY task_status = 'OPEN' DESC,task_status ASC");
```

Alternatively,

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM session_tasks
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN task_status = 'OPEN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
         task_status ASC"); //Ordering starts with Open, then in Ascending order
```

Here is one more solution using Codeigniter active record that works. Note the usage of double quotes when using string literal.

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
$this->db->from('session_tasks');
$this->db->order_by("task_status = 'OPEN'", 'DESC');
$this->db->order_by('task_status');
$query = $this->db->get();
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$this->db->order_by("task_status", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get_where('session_tasks', array('task_status'=>'open'));
```

to check the documentation [click here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Now, I can't get the other rows where its `task_status != Open` -.-

Comment: use 1,2,3 in your db for task_status and remove where condition...give 1 to 'open' and for order $this->db->order_by("task_status", "asc");

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
// set this to false so that _protect_identifiers skips escaping:
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;

// your order_by line:
$this -> db -> order_by('FIELD ( products.country_id, 2, 0, 1 )');

 // important to set this back to TRUE or ALL of your queries from now on will be non-escaped:
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE;
```

[Source](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1846)